# What data type is suitable to handle binary data in ActiveX method?

Tags: delphi, activex, binary-data

I'm writing an ActiveX control for my friend, that should encapsulate encryption routines. It will be used from VB6 primarily. What data type should I choose for binary data like encryption key, initialization vector, input and output data so that it would be convenient for my friend to use it from VB6?

I'm using Delphi 7 to write this ActiveX, if that matters. One choice is to use hexadecimal strings. What can be the other?

Comment: In the first hand, what your *friend* himself finds convenient to use? ;-)

Comment: @user539484 He says, hex strings ;) But I'm still looking for MORE convenient solution ;)

Comment: hex strings, or base64 encoding etc sounds like a poor hack to me.

Comment: @FractalizeR, so does my answer suits your needs?

Answer (score 4):

VB6 Binary data stored in Byte variables and arrays.

```
Dim arrData() As Byte
```

VB6 Application should pass that variable to your Delphi COM as `OleVariant`.
Delphi COM can convert `VarArray` to `TStream` and vice versa:

```
procedure VariantToStream(const v :OleVariant; Stream: TStream);
var
  p : pointer;
  lo, hi, size: Integer;
begin
  lo := VarArrayLowBound(v,  1);
  hi := VarArrayHighBound (v, 1);
  if (lo >= 0) and (hi >= 0) then
  begin
    size := hi - lo + 1;
    p := VarArrayLock (v);
    try
      Stream.WriteBuffer (p^, size);
    finally
      VarArrayUnlock (v);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure StreamToVariant(Stream: TStream; var v: OleVariant);
var
  p : pointer;
  size: Integer;
begin
  size := Stream.Size - Stream.Position;
  v := VarArrayCreate ([0, size - 1], varByte);
  if size > 0 then
  begin
    p := VarArrayLock (v);
    try
      Stream.ReadBuffer (p^, size);
    finally
      VarArrayUnlock (v);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Usage in the `CoClass` unit:

```
// HRESULT _stdcall BinaryTest([in] VARIANT BinIn, [out, retval] VARIANT * BinOut );
function TMyComClass.BinaryTest(BinIn: OleVariant): OleVariant; safecall;
var
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    VariantToStream(BinIn, Stream);
    Stream.Position := 0;

    // do something with Stream ...

    // ... and return some Binary data to caller (* BinOut)
    Stream.Position := 0;
    StreamToVariant(Stream, Result);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

---

This is the most common approach to use `SAFEARRAY` of Bytes with Binary data via COM automation.
Stuffing the data into a `BSTR` (Hex strings, Base64 Encoding etc..) sound kinda ugly to me and seems more like a hack.

Comment: It is possible to put binary data into a `BSTR` without encoding it. The COM API has `SysAllocStringByteLen()` and `SysStringByteLen()` functions for working with binary `BSTR`s. This is not a hack, but it is not a commonly used feature.  A `SAFEARRAY` containing `VT_UI1` elements is a better choice for passing around binary data, though (`IStream` is even better).

Comment: @RemyLebeau-TeamB, Thanks for the info and edit :) I was referring to a hack by *encoding* the `BSTR`.