# Passing array of bytes to an ActiveX

Tags: arrays, com, activex, byte

I want to pass a array of bytes to ActiveX. I am using delphi 7 and i'm using a InProcess Server (DLL).

I am using a pointer to the array of bytes and the size of the array, passing it to the InProcess Server. It is working well. I did this because I need performance. Does anyone see any trouble in this approach?

I see a post that is very similar: [What data type is suitable to handle binary data in ActiveX method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265884/what-data-type-is-suitable-to-handle-binary-data-in-activex-method) but nobody gave this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the byte array as pointer together with size information is just fine.

However, some programming languages support only a small subset of all possible types. For example, Visual Basic for Application (not VB.NET) can only handle Automation compatible data types (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc237562(v=prot.20).aspx), and even not all of them (no support for 16bit unsigned integers, for example). To be on the safe side, I always use SAFEARRAYs whenever there is no good argument against it.

Also note that using non-automation compatible interfaces forces you to provide your own marshalling code in case you wanted to use your component OutProc. Since you mention that you intend to use your component only InProc, this should not worry you.

Regards,
Stuart